# this.value not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the working example in javascript

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvBM9/)

and here where i put it and `(this.value)` not working

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#submit').bind("click",function() 
    { 
        var imgVal = $('#file').val();
        var imgName = $('#image_n').val(); 
        var imgDes = $('#image_description').val(); 

        var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
        all_select[i].onchange = function () {
        alert(this.value);
        }
        }
```

Any idea what is the problem or how to fix it?
BTW (this) don't appear colored as u can see here

Comment: (Also, the code that *is* in your demo works, so far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Asad yea my code is 2700 lines i just copy the important part

Comment: @David Thomas working as javascript

Comment: Code in demo works for me as well.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

Comment: But 'the important part' should be the part that reproduces your problem, the code you posted in your Fiddle does not. And...what? Yes, it works as JavaScript. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` changes within closures.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  $('#submit').bind("click",function() 
  { 
    var submitButton = $(this); // <-- The call here refers to the #submit click
    var imgVal = $('#file').val();
    var imgName = $('#image_n').val(); 
    var imgDes = $('#image_description').val(); 

    var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
      all_select[i].onchange = function () {
         var selectElement = $(this); // <-- The call here refers to the select change
         alert(submitButton.val()); // <-- What do you mean to alert?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `submitButton` is a jQuery object. you should use `submitButton.val()` or just set `submitButton = this;`.

Comment: I don't care what OP does *with* the object, the important part is the encapsulation.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the OP does not mean to alert the static value of whatever `#submit` happens to be. Also, I haven't come across the use of the word "encapsulate" in the context you're using it before.

Comment: "closure" was the term I was looking for. Edited.

Comment: @Joe Frambach thanks working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you bind the `onchange` event handler inside the "bind submit" handler so it is not added until that submit event fires.  I would suggest moving it outside that other as such:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on("click", function () {
        var imgVal = $('#file').val();
        var imgName = $('#image_n').val();
        var imgDes = $('#image_description').val();
    });
    $("select").on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

NOTE: IF for some reason you like your syntax, you can still use that as such:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on("click", function () {
        var imgVal = $('#file').val();
        var imgName = $('#image_n').val();
        var imgDes = $('#image_description').val();
    });

    var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
        all_select[i].onchange = function () {
            alert(this.value);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Bro this.value is not working i voted up for the idea of putting it outside

Comment: I see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/VvBM9/1/ and the alternative syntax here: http://jsfiddle.net/VvBM9/2/

Comment: yea in the demo it's working but here it's not javascript it's jquery it have to be written the way that Joe answered

Comment: When you change a select, it alerts the value of the chosen select.  What am I missing here in my understanding?

Comment: but when u click the button (in your demo) it doesn't show alert

Comment: No, your code is an event handler on the change event.  Are you saying you wish to see all the currently selected values on the submit button click as well?  That is an entirely DIFFERENT question, but easily accomplished.  Please clarify intent therein.